# Removing Android error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent from another class

Tags: java, android, class, inheritance

I'm currently working on an android project and I keep running into the error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=cn.ingenic.glasssync.SYNC_SERVICE }

I know newer versions of android require the Service intent to be explicit, the service intent it's referring to is however in the imported class file SyncModule.java in the line

```
private final void bind(IBinder service) {
        if (this.mService != null) {
            Log.d("SyncModule", "Module:" + this.mName + " already bonded.");
        } else {
            if (service == null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("cn.ingenic.glasssync.SYNC_SERVICE");
                this.mContext.bindService(intent, this.mServiceConnection, 1);
            } else {
                this.mService = Stub.asInterface(service);
                if (this.mService != null) {
                    try {
                        this.mService.registModule(this.mName, this.mCallback);
                    } catch (RemoteException var3) {
                        Log.e("SyncModule", "", var3);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

The place where it breaks is in the local class

```
public SmsModule(String name, Context context) {

        super(name, context, true);
```

Where it calls the constructor from it's SyncModule class, since this is an inherited class file i'm not able to edit the source code is there any work around I could do to fix this error?

Comment: Contact the developers of that library and see if they have an up-to-date version of the library. The restriction that you cite has been in place for years.

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.